# Mark label show always is not showing for all data

Tags: tableau-api

It looks like the size of the boxes are too small for the labels. But is there a way to force the labels to show? Mark labels are set to always show and I tried smaller fonts.

[image: Labels]

Answer (score 1):

In label options, check the option to "Allow labels to overlap other marks".

http://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/labels-missing-from-view

Comment: "Allow labels to overlap other marks" is missing from my label options. I do have multiple mark labels.

Comment: Sounds like from this discussion that the option may not be available on treemaps. I haven't found documentation that supports that, but seems to be true. https://community.tableau.com/thread/185324

Answer (score 1):

It can be bit messy sometime to allow labels to overlap.
you can try annotate and then choose mark for a relatively small section of your viz

Comment: You can also select specific marks and choose always show or always hide the label for those marks

Comment: @AlexBlakemore you cannot set alignment for specific labels. so they might overlap, while using annotate you can choose any position for your label also you can add other relevant information if you want

Comment: Correct that you can't set alignment for specific labels on a tree map, but you can select specific marks to always show (or always) hide their labels. (You can also manually  reposition individual labels when you have a continuous axis)